# How to count the number of data loaded into the cache but not used?

Tags: caching, x86, perf, cpu-cache, intel-pmu

The following two situations may cause data to be loaded into the cache but not used:

1. Incorrect prefetch judgment
2. Partial access of cacheline

Both of these situations may have negative impact on system performance, so I want to monitor the severity of these situations in the system.

I am using Intel 8352Y (Icelake) and AMD 9654 (Zen4).

**Is there corresponding PMU events or other means to count such events on these two platforms?**

Comment: Skylake has a perf event `l2_lines_out.useless_hwpf` that tracks lines that were loaded by HW prefetch (not SW prefetch) but not used before eviction.  For (2) partial access, perhaps some software tool like valgrind or a full simulator like Gem5?  I doubt hardware could track that for you since it would require extra tracking per byte, like an extra 64 tag bits of metadata per cache line.  (vs. just 1 bit per line for detecting useless HW prefetch.)